# Does beginTransaction in Hibernate allocate a new DB connection?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, orm, transactions

Just wondering if beginning a new transaction in Hibernate actually allocates a connection to the DB?

I'm concerned b/c our server begins a new transaction for each request received, even if that request doesn't interact with the DB.  We're seeing DB connections as a major bottleneck, so I'm wondering if I should take the time narrow the scope of my transactions.

Searched everywhere and haven't been able to find a good answer.  The very simple code is here:

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) Context.getContext().getBean("sessionFactory");
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
```

thanks very much!
a

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Updated per Pascal Thivent's comment)

Each `Session` creates a database connection if there is a need for that - e.g. if a transaction is started. The connection is not opened with the mere creation of the session.

To overcome this, you can use a [connecetion pool](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToconfiguretheC3P0connectionpool) so that connections are reused. Or you can make sure (as it appears you did) that no transaction is started automatically.

([This](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/04/read-only-transactions-with-spring-and.html) discusses read-only transactions. Take a look.)

Comment: Thanks, we are using a connection pool already.  By not beginning a transaction by default we were able to massively reduce the load on our database.

Comment: Actually, the connection is lazy-loaded in a `Session`. See my answer for details.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent hm, interesting, and logical :)
@illscience please change the accepted answer

Answer (score 16):

According to the section [11.1. Session and transaction scopes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics) of the Hibernate documentation:

> A `SessionFactory` is an
>   expensive-to-create, threadsafe
>   object, intended to be shared by all
>   application threads. It is created
>   once, usually on application startup,
>   from a `Configuration` instance.
>
> A `Session` is an inexpensive,
>   non-threadsafe object that should be
>   used once and then discarded for: a
>   single request, a conversation or a
>   single unit of work. **A `Session` will
>   not obtain a JDBC `Connection`, or a
>   `Datasource`, unless it is needed.** It
>   will not consume any resources until
>   used.
>
> **In order to reduce lock contention in
>   the database, a database transaction
>   has to be as short as possible. Long
>   database transactions will prevent
>   your application from scaling to a
>   highly concurrent load.** It is not
>   recommended that you hold a database
>   transaction open during user think
>   time until the unit of work is
>   complete.

Now, to answer your question:

- getting a `Session` does **not** immediately acquire a connection (the connection is lazy loaded)
- but calling `beginTransaction()` will cause the load of the connection for the given `Session`
- subsequent calls will reuse the same `connection`

Look at `org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl#beginTransaction()` and go through the code for more details.